# Is There A Portable Java

Tags: java, portability

i was just wondering if anyone knew of a portable java IDE/Compiler? Something like an iPod but not so advanced, that let's you work with and compile java?
Just thought it would be a cool idea :P

Comment: If an iPod is too advanced, I'm not really sure what you'd be expecting…

Answer (score 3):

[This serves the purpose](http://javafiddle.net/). We can compile the programs without requiring Java compiler on our machine.

Comment: an alternative is ideone.com

Answer (score 2):

There is an IDE for Android which supports this, see [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Search for drJava. Is a pretty complex editor and includes a(n Eclipse) compiler.
Unfortunatelly, the project seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iOS device (iPhone, iPod touch or iPad) at hand, you can jailbreak it and install Java from Cydia. This gives you the compiler and the VM. However, it's old and limited to command line functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://ideone.com/. This is a website for compiling and running java applications Here you can create an account and save all your example programs, which you can later refer from different location or even share it with others.
You can also practice other computer languages in it. It supports more than 40 programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given any thought about using codenameone platform?  http://www.codenameone.com/